# Clickable toolbar in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, toolbar, clickable

I am newest in Xamarin and have question for developers with more experiences.

I want to hide custom picker when user clicks anywhere any view in app. This working with view where is custom picker opened, but when I click on toolbar he remains opened. This problem is existing only on iOS, Android work as expected.

Could i make whole toolbar to be clickable and how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Making toolbar/navigation-bar clickable just to close picker is not intuitive thing to do. I believe your users should understand this. Besides native picker has "done" button, you can implement something similar to this to close the picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Picker Toolbar you can set UIBarButtonItem to add Done button. Then you can add a Click Event for the Done button and write following code in it.

```
YourPicker.RemoveFromSuperview();
YourPickerView.RemoveFromSuperview();
textField.ResignFirstResponder();
```